# Ошибка в python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

У меня есть код который ищет товар в дб MONGODB

```
name_product = self.values[0] if self.grant else self.values[0] + " no gr"
product = self.product.get(name_product)
price = (self.price.find_one({"type_nitro": nitro_types.index(name_product)}))["price"]
view = Confirm(self.member, name_product, self.values[0], price)
self.embed = disnake.Embed(
    title="Покупка",
    description=f"Вы уверены, что хотите купить **{name_product}** за **{price} RUB**",
    color=0x2f3136
).set_thumbnail(url=self.member.avatar.url)
await interaction.response.edit_message(
    embed = self.embed,
    view=view
)
```

Но в консоле данная ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

MONGODB
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
price = (self.price.find_one({"type_nitro": nitro_types.index(name_product)}))["price"]
```

а что делаете, когда запись не найдена?

вы бы проверили, что вам выдает `find_one` и если None, то не стоит обращаться `["price"]`, а верните хотя бы 0 или ещё как-то обработайте ситуацию

Comment: Запись не найдена когда я покупаю товар который находится в reast.price